# When does Android JobScheduler remove completed Job from getAllPendingJobs()?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am investigating android JobScheduler in Android O preview.

It all works fine while I schedule my one off job within a single Activity.

I can see that my job appears in the `List<JobInfo>`'s returned by `getAllPendingJobs()` while it is pending/running. It is removed from this list once it has completed.

However when I start the job from `Activity A` and switch to `Activity B` the job is not being removed from the `getAllPendingJobs()` `List<JobInfo>`.

Why is my completed job being kept in the AllPendingJobs List<>?

This is how I start my Job

```
    syncJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    final JobInfo.Builder jobInfoBuilder = new JobInfo.Builder(SYNC_JOB_SCHEDULER_ID, new ComponentName(getPackageName(), JobSchedulerMendeleySyncable.class.getName()));
    jobInfoBuilder.setMinimumLatency(MIN_LATENCY_MILLIS_ZERO);
    jobInfoBuilder.setBackoffCriteria(INITIAL_BACKOFF_MILLIS, BACKOFF_POLICY_EXPONENTIAL);
    final int jobScheduledResult = syncJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfoBuilder.build());
```

UPDATE 0001
How do i detect a scheduled job has completed?